# How do you get the current location of a specific idevice?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

The core location framework gives us the current location of the device that is using the app, but is there a property or method that provides the location of a completely different idevice if you want to be located by someone else who also uses the same app?  Hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Core location is using the GPS on your device for your location. Your app doesn't have access to the GPS on another device, so it cannot directly access the other device's location.

Instead your app would have to be running on that other device. Then it could access the device location, and upload it to a server somewhere.

The app running on your device could then download this data from the server to display the location of the other device.